# Does a duplicated Ambassador's mapping takes down Kubernetes services?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy a cloned website in a second namespace. But I forgot to change the URL for Ambassador's mapping resource. So both clones are the same URL https://mywebsite.dev which supposed to be https://mywebsite.dev and https://testing.mywebsite.dev. The main website was taken down soon after I `kubectl apply` the minor website. Both sites are offline now. Basically that means I ran the mapping.yaml twice in different namespaces.

**Is there any chance that duplicated mapping causes the error? How to fix that?**

This is the yaml file:

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v1
kind: Mapping
metadata:
  name: mywebsite
spec:
  cors:
    credentials: true
    headers: x-csrf-token,Content-Type,Authorization
    methods: POST, PATCH, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
    origins:
    - https://mywebsite.dev
  host: mywebsite.dev
  load_balancer:
    cookie:
      name: stickyname
    policy: ring_hash
  prefix: /
  resolver: endpoint
  service: http://my-website-service.default
  timeout_ms: 60000
```

Comment: You should have also added the Ambassador LoadBalancer IP mapping to your domain.Is that right ? 
So even though if you have deployed it twice it will have a different loadbalancer . It shouldnt effect the other deployment given that in your dns you still have the previous loadbalancer configured

Comment: I'm not sure about LoadBalancer IP? I only have 1 ambassador deployment in namespace default. Could you give me an example for IP config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems an error from Ambassador 0.86 when it has a duplicated/bad record of mapping, then got stuck there, doesn't accept any new mapping record. I fixed it by delete ambassador pods then let the deployment recreate them. It works fine later.